# File download in restful webservices

Tags: rest, web-services, jax-rs

I am using restful web services to download a file in Linux operating system. But I am getting an error as shown in the image. I am using Linux operating system. 
[image: ![error]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwxm6.png)

Please help me to resolve this error.
 Entire project can be downloaded from the below link 
 [Project download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kgbd9pxQL03XmpcTyDPKuCChJxFILQL_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I see that your project does not contain all the resources needed for JAX-RS runtime.

I put the necessary files in your project. Download the zip here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VGiWugSegmPFmFAI-uWu3AB3OG6Sxi0a

You can run com.java4s.Main directly via maven with:

```
mvn clean package exec:java -DmainClass=com.java4s.Main
```

I have created a resource that you can use to download any file from your filesystem using :

http://localhost:8080/myapp/download/fs/[completeFilename]

replace [completeFilename] with the absolute path of a file in the filesystem, for eg:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/download/fs/home/bill/Desktop/hero.txt

Comment: "I see that your project does not contain all the resources needed for JAX-RS runtime."  Its a working example in another OS . Please click on this link . https://www.java4s.com/web-services/download-files-from-jax-rs-restful-web-service/

Comment: I changed the return type of method getCustomerDataFile() to File and deleted lines which had ResponseBuilder object. In the end of function I returned the file object . This diplayed the file contents in browser . But I wanted to download the file with a dialog box .